# bulk renaming files rearranging file names based on delimiter

Tags: awk, sed, file-rename

I have seen questions that are close to this but I have not seen the exact answer I need and can't seem to get my head wrapped around the regex, awk, sed, grep, rename that I would need to make it happen.

I have files in one directory sequentially named from multiple sub directories of a different directory created using find piped to xargs.

Command I used:

```
find `<dir1>` -name "*.png" | xargs cp -t `<dir2>`
```

This resulted in the second directory containing duplicate filenames sequentially named as follows:

`<name>`.png
`<name>`.png.~1~
`<name>`.png.~2~
...
`<name>`.png.~n~

What I would like to do is take all files ending in ~*~ and rename it as follows:

`<name>`.#.png   where the '#" is the number between the "~"s at the end of the file name

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Perl's `rename` (stand alone command):

```
rename -nv 's/^([^.]+)\.(.+)\.~([0-9]+)~/$1.$3.$2/' *
```

If everything looks fine remove option `-n`.

Comment: Cyrus to advance this one farther step, how about now matter what the file extension is, whether png, jpg, jpeg, ico, etc., it would use the correct extension.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an easier way to this, but here is a small shell script using `grep` and `awk` to achieve what you wanted

```
for i in $(ls|grep ".png."); do 
name=$(echo $i|awk -F'png' '{print $1}');
n=$(echo $i|awk -F'~' '{print $2}'); 
mv $i $name$n.png; 
done
```

Comment: I should have mentioned in the question that I was looking for a one line answer - which Cyrus provided above.